# How to get product count of reviews/rating by python-amazon-sp-api?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-selling-partner-api

I try to get Amazon products reviews and rating information from python-amazon-sp-api.
The methods I have found in endpoints Products(get_item_offers) and Catalog (get_item) don't response reviews related information.

Am I not finding the right method?

I didn't find related method in this api documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way today to get those data through SP-API.
You either have to scrap it or use an external API like rainforest that does so.